# C# - Mysql . Choose random with subcondition

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the columns :

`pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 id`

`pos1-5 -> varchar , id -> int`

I'm using the query:

```
Query = "select distinct * from (SELECT * FROM database.turkey2 t1 WHERE pos2='"+comboBox2.Text+"' and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM database.turkey2used t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)) as t3 order by rand() limit "+amount+"  ;";
```

Meaning the user will choose pos2(will make it static) while the rest is random , the amount will be set by the user as well.
What I'm trying to do is to add a condition in this query that force at least 2 diffrent pos(positions) that must be chosen in random.
meaning , I don't want to get 2 or more rows with the same valuse at pos1,2,3,4 and only pos5 will be diffrent(igonore the id - and the rule dosen't apply only to pose 5 of course).

I solved the problem by runnning another query on the already select amount - but that's not good because if the user asked for 200 combinitions then after the "fix" he may lose some rows.

some other info - it's a medium size db (about 10m rows).
Please keep the solution simple because I'm rather new to mysql and c#.
Thanks.